# Why is my string becoming nil when used as the title of an action sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

In an app I am currently writing, I have a string named 'User' which stores the user's name for a game. The value of the string, when printed anywhere else in the Swift file, prints the value that I have set, as an optional.

If I try to use this string as the title of an action sheet action, the string is automatically set to nil, which I can see as both the title of the action and which is printed when I ask it to print(user).

If anyone could shed some light as to why this is happening, or how to prevent it, that would be great. I have also posted my Swift file below, thanks.

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!

var user:String!
var playerTwo:String!
var playerThree:String!
var playerFour:String!
var playerFive:String!
var playerSix:String!

var userCards = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstView?.isHidden = false
    secondView?.isHidden = true

}

@IBAction func valueDidChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        firstView.isHidden = false
        secondView.isHidden = true
    case 1:
        firstView.isHidden = true
        secondView.isHidden = false
    default:
        break;
    }
}

@IBAction func confirm(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "What would you like to do?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let userButton = UIAlertAction(title: user /* Here I have tried with putting both 'user', and "\(user)"*/, style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("User button tapped")
    })

    let  deleteButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete button test", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("Delete button tapped")
    })

    let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("Cancel button tapped")
    })


    alertController.addAction(userButton)
    alertController.addAction(deleteButton)
    alertController.addAction(cancelButton)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
}
```

The value is passed into the above file directly from this code in another file:

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

```
    if segue.identifier == "showMainController" {

        let VC = segue.destination as! MainViewController

        VC.user = self.user

        if playerTwo != nil {

            VC.playerTwo = self.playerTwo

        }

        if playerThree != nil {

            VC.playerThree = self.playerThree

        }

        if playerFour != nil {

            VC.playerFour = self.playerFour

        }

        if playerFive != nil {

            VC.playerFive = self.playerFive

        }

        if playerSix != nil {

            VC.playerSix = self.playerSix

        }
    }
}
```

The value is, however, passed through several view controllers, and is initially set here:

```
if (meTextField.text?.isEmpty)! == false {

        let p1 = meTextField.text!
        initialPlayersDict["player1"] = "\(p1)"

        if errLabelNotBlank {

            errorLabel.text = ""
            errLabelNotBlank = false

        }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you set the value for `user`?

Comment: I set it in the previous ViewController, and pass it in via a Prepare(forSegue:), using the text entered into a text field

Comment: Could you please post that code too?

Comment: Done, I personally don't think the previous files would be related, as the string is fine with retaining it's value throughout the project until put into the action sheet. Either way, if you could figure anything out it'd be great.

Comment: Log the value of `VC.user`after setting it in `prepare` method. What do you get ?

Comment: I entered "Player1", in the text field to set it, and it successfully prints "Player1" in the console.

Comment: From what I see in the code posted, the text is saved in "initialPlayersDict", not in self.user.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the issue, I transfer the value through several ViewControllers, I just missed out the middle few as to not put hundreds of lines of code in the file when practically every one of them has the same prepare(forSegue:). As said, the variable does have the value that it is intended to at the beginning of the class MainViewController, it only goes wrong as soon as it is entered into the Action Sheet, thereby as I see it, only the first block of code I posted is relevant.

Comment: Quick question here: do you mean to use `(meTextField.text?.isEmpty)! == false` in the last code segment `if` statement as opposed to `((meTextField.text?.isEmpty) != false)` ? That doesn't seem like it's correct, and it could cause you issues as it tries to get called by the program.

Comment: your `user` is type of `String` not `Optional<String>` so every time you tries access to it and it is nil then app should crash. So probably your user is set to "nil" (String)

Comment: No, I intended to do it that way, I was checking if the text field had something in, effectively saying that if the text field isn't empty, run the following code. The double negative in the one you state would also work, but only if I inverted the code to have an extra statement in, and put the current code in what would be the following else statement. (Your code runs if it is empty, mine runs if it is not).

Comment: @Mateusz I see... but the app doesn't crash, and I know that the String isn't nil up to that point, so how does it actually become nil?

Comment: it is not `nil` but `"nil"` ;P otherwise app should crash instead of print 'nil' in console on call `print(user)`